# PHP Image script

Tags: php, image

So my plan is instead of adding a  style to each picture or making different images with different sizes, I made this script:

```
/*FILENAME image.php*/
    if(isset($_GET['size'])){
        $image['size']  = $_GET['size'];
        $size = explode('x', $image['size']);
        $image['width'] = $size[0];
        $image['height'] = $size[1];
    } else {
        $image['size']  = null;
    }
echo "<img src='images/".$image['name'].".jpeg' style='width:".$image['width'].";   height:".$image['height'].";'>";
```

But it doesn't work, In one of my scripts, I have this:

```
echo '<img id="img_01" src="image.php?name='.$row2['name'].'&size=150x160" data-zoom-image="image.php?name='.$row2['name'].'&size=150x160"/>';
```

And the browser echo's just a missing image. How could I make my script work? I know there must be a way because I remember doing something like this with an open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how dynamic images work. Image.php has to actually output the raw binary content of an image (open a jpg file in a text editor, that's what the PHP file should generate).

Take a look at the gd functions, like http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php, which should have some examples that will help